# Excel formula gives a different answer when in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an Excel sheet that I have to make into an HTML/CSS/JavaScript page. For this I need the formula: `100*(50+15)*(100%+100%*50%)` in Excel to have the same outcome in JavaScript. Of course this doesn't work because the `%` sign has another meaning in JavaScript.

Does anyone know how to fix this? Of course I wouldn't mind installing jQuery or other things to make it work.

Comment: You can also represent percentages as fractions of 1 as in `100% == 1`, `50% == 0.5` etc. Then you can just plug those numbers directly into your equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it, in this way:

```
var math = 100*(50+15)*(1+1*0.5);
console.log(math);
```

The result will be 9750? Is it right?

Comment: Oh I see how you did it! Not really familiar with how excel works... But now I get it. Thank you very much!

Comment: @ThijsVijver that's simple math:) 1 it's like 100% and 0.5 it's like 50%.

Comment: @ThijsVijver glad to help you